# Add URL hash to reveal.js "Upcoming" speaker notes slide

Tags: javascript, reveal.js

I am using [reveal.js](https://revealjs.com/) for a slide presentation. Reveal.js provides a "Speaker View" window. In Reveal.js's "Tall" layout, it shows an "Upcoming" slide in an overlay box called "Upcoming".

To help me keep track of where I am, I would like to change that text to include the hash portion of the URL, like "#1" or #/1/0/1".
(The hash portion of a Reveal.js URL is its slide-deck position.)

How can I do this?

Here is a screenshot of the "Speaker View" window:

[image: reveal.js speaker window in tall format]

Comment: This question currently deserves a close vote for reason "Needs debugging details", IMHO, even if the bounty prevents that. Please provide a proper [mre] of what you currently have.

Comment: This is not a debugging question. I am asking for expanding a feature of a popular slide-presentation package. There are lots of demo slide decks. See github.com/rajgoel/reveal.js-demos. Pick any one of them. Extend this feature to cover one and you'll cover all of them.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is a way better solution than this, but if you need a quick, easy and safe solution, I think you can use this. Seeing the documentation, I don't think there's any API for this, so I had to come up with own solution. The way I see it, the speaker view is using `iframe` to show the upcoming slide and unfortunately it doesn't send any callback when the upcoming slide has changed (so the speaker view doesn't know the state of the upcoming slide). Normally, you would want to use `postMessage` to send back the state after the upcoming iframe succeed changing the slide, but this approach might break something if you're not careful. So my proposed approach is to basically synchronize the `Upcoming` label with the `hash` url of the iframe. The easiest way to do this is by using `setInterval` to do a polling and get the hash value and append it to the `Upcoming` label.

First thing you must do is to open this file `plugin/notes/speaker-view.html` (I assume you have this file in your project directory since [it should be added](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/blob/master/plugin/notes/speaker-view.html) when you clone the original repository), then look for this function `setupIframes( data )`, then add these codes at the end of the function, like so:

```
        /**
         * Creates the preview iframes.
         */
        function setupIframes( data ) {
          ...
          upcomingSlide.setAttribute("height", 512);
          upcomingSlide.setAttribute("src", upcomingURL);


          // ADD BELOW CODES
          setInterval(function () {
            const upcomingLabel = document.querySelector(
              "#upcoming-slide .overlay-element"
            );
            upcomingLabel.innerHTML =
              "Upcoming " + upcomingSlide.contentWindow.location.hash;
          }, 300);


          ...
          document.querySelector("#upcoming-slide").appendChild(upcomingSlide);
        }
```

After that, you need to rebuild the project, run this command:

```
npm run build
```

After the build is done, you can start run the project again. You can also change the `300` (300ms) to maybe `1000` (1s) if you want, the smaller the values, the more synchronized it will be.

If you're wondering why I don't propose using `hashchange` event on the iframe, it's because it doesn't work on this case, I tested it.

Comment: Can't you use the [`hashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/hashchange_event) event to detect changes in the upcoming slide?

Comment: @Heiko Theißen I tried using that on this iframe, and it doesn't get triggered, thus the setInterval solution

Comment: I tried the hashchange approach. Not working for me.  See the comment under the other answer. setInterval works! Many thanks to both of you for helping me here.  I'll leave this hang out for a little bit in case you or others find a way to improve. After a little bit though I'll accept this answer.  Thanks again.

Comment: Found out why hashchange didn't work, see my reworked answer. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Damzaky's answer, the change of the fragment of the iframed URL can happen either via `location.hash = ...` or via `history.replaceState(...)` (see [here](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/blob/334abff10f8e854ca121758187cfbaa186f34321/js/controllers/location.js#L143-L158)), and the latter variant does *not* trigger the [`hashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/hashchange_event) event.

I therefore suggest to introduce a new event `slide` and register a handler for this on the `upcomingSlide` window.

In function
[`writeURL`](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/blob/334abff10f8e854ca121758187cfbaa186f34321/js/controllers/location.js#L145):

```js
if( config.history ) {
  window.location.hash = hash;
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event("slide")); // inserted line
}
```

In function [`replaceState`](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/blob/334abff10f8e854ca121758187cfbaa186f34321/js/controllers/location.js#L174):

```js
replaceState( url ) {
  window.history.replaceState( null, null, url );
  this.replaceStateTimestamp = Date.now();
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event("slide")); // inserted line
}
```

In [`speaker-view.html`](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/blob/334abff10f8e854ca121758187cfbaa186f34321/plugin/notes/speaker-view.html#L552):

```js
upcomingSlide = document.createElement( 'iframe' );
upcomingSlide.setAttribute( 'width', 640 );
upcomingSlide.setAttribute( 'height', 512 );
upcomingSlide.addEventListener("load", function() { // inserted block
  upcomingSlide.contentWindow.addEventListener("slide", function() {
    const upcomingLabel = document.querySelector(
      "#upcoming-slide .overlay-element"
    );
    upcomingLabel.innerHTML =
      "Upcoming " + upcomingSlide.contentWindow.location.hash;
  });
});
upcomingSlide.setAttribute( 'src', upcomingURL );
```

The [`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) event occurs when a page (a new presentation) is loaded into the iframe `upcomingSlide`. At this point, the `upcomingSlide.contentWindow` is available and can register its event handler.

That removes the need to use `setInterval`.

Comment: I have not been able to get this to work.  I have been able to get the `setInterval` solution to work.The problem I see when I replace the above at the same place that I put the ` setInterval solution, is that I get "Uncaught TypeErorr: upcomingSlide.contentWindow is null" . (I don't know how to attach a screenshot inside a comment.)

Comment: I updated the code, but alas this isn't working either. (It fails better in that it doesn't prevent notes from loading like the first try.)  The javascript console shows:  Uncaught TypeError: upcomingLabel is null.  Somehow I guess the querySelector is failing. I don't see the error though.

Comment: After forking reveal.js and actually trying it out, I have augmented my answer again.

Comment: I tried the most recent changes which include adding the slide event and rebuilding the entire reveal.js code (in addition to the plugin code).  Not working for me. I am not seeing console errors, and I can set a debug breakpoint to see that the event gets triggered.  Although my short-term need is solved, I think the longer term desirability is to add this feature to reveal.js. It is there where I think this code would more useful over the other solution.  So consider offering this to that project. I will probably mention this myself after the conference is over. Thanks for proposing this.

Comment: Strange, it worked for me. Did you see the event handler (in `speaker-view.html`) being called in the debugger?

Comment: I have reverted the code right now. I will pick this up after the conference in a month or so when trying to get it into the reveal.js code base. I could have done something wrong. That is why I work on debuggers. But unfortunately now is not the right time to spend working on this.